# Python - Pass index value dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading a deeply nested dictionary called response and getting a formatted output

```
 response = {u'ResultSet': {u'Rows': [
{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'Table_name'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'Validation_Scenario'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'No_of_Records'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'Result'}]}, 
{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'ABC'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'01_scenario2'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'100'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'FAIL'}]}, 
{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'ABC'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'02_scenario1'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'200'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'FAIL'}]}, 
{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'ABC'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'03_scenario3'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'300'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'PASS'}]}, 
{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'ABC'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'04_scenario4'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'400'}, {u'VarCharValue': u'PASS'}]}]}}

print (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][0][Data][0][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
       ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][0][Data][1][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
       ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][0][Data][2][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
       ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][0][Data][3][VarCharValue]}".format(response))) 

Output: ('Table_name', 'Validation_Scenario', 'No_of_Records', 'Result')
```

Now when i want to loop through the indexes [0][Data] from 0 to 4 i am getting Python - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

```
for i in range(4):
     print (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][i][Data][0][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
            ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][i][Data][1][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
            ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][i][Data][2][VarCharValue]}".format(response)),
            ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][i][Data][3][VarCharValue]}".format(response))) 

Error :TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I understand that since there is " " i is treated as a string but i wanted to know how can i pass the index values dynamically?

Comment: your `response` isn't valid python.

Comment: Why use a format string to extract values from a dict? If you use normal code to get the values from the dict, you won't have that problem with the `i` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings. If you really want to do this with format strings, you have to construct it dynamically:

```
for i in range(4):
     print ((("{0[ResultSet][Rows][" + str(i) + "][Data][0][VarCharValue]}").format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][" + str(i) + "][Data][1][VarCharValue]}").format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][" + str(i) + "][Data][2][VarCharValue]}").format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][" + str(i) + "][Data][3][VarCharValue]}").format(response)))
```

or:

```
for i in range(4):
     print ((("{0[ResultSet][Rows][%d][Data][0][VarCharValue]}" % i).format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][%d][Data][1][VarCharValue]}" % i).format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][%d][Data][2][VarCharValue]}" % i).format(response)),
            (("{0[ResultSet][Rows][%d][Data][3][VarCharValue]}" % i).format(response)))
```

But it would be simpler to just access the nested element in code, not the format string:

```
for i in range(4):
    print (response['ResultSet']['Rows'][i]['Data'][0]['VarCharValue'],
           response['ResultSet']['Rows'][i]['Data'][1]['VarCharValue'],
           response['ResultSet']['Rows'][i]['Data'][2]['VarCharValue'],
           response['ResultSet']['Rows'][i]['Data'][3]['VarCharValue'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answers.
    Option1 :I am getting ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
    Option2 :Works fine
    Option3 :I am getting 'KeyError: 0'

Comment: #1 needed another set of parentheses.

Comment: #3 didn't need `[0]` at the beginning, I misunderstood the `{0`.